# Pass int array from one method to another as argument

Tags: java

I am trying to do a school work and I'm having problem passing an int array from a method to another as an argument.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Eac4P1_002 {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

//Método main
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Eac4P1_002 programa = new Eac4P1_002();
        programa.inicio();
}
//Método principal
    public void inicio() {
        presentacion();
        intro();
        resultado();
}

//Presentación
    public void presentacion(){
        System.out.println("Hola, bienvenid@ al ejercicio 2!\n"
                + "El programa os pedirá la edad de dos clases, "
                + "en enteros y comprueba si los valores de la segunda clase "
                + "son más grandes que los de la primera.");
    }
//Inserción de datos
    public void intro(){
        System.out.println("De que medida necesitas que sean las clases?");
        int medida = scanner.nextInt();
        int clase1 [] = new int[medida];
        int clase2 [] = new int[medida];
        int contador = 0;
        int posicion = 1;

        System.out.println("Ahora deberás introducir el valor de cada "
                    + "posición de la clase inicial.");
        while (contador < clase1.length){
                System.out.print("Escribe el valor de la posición "+posicion+": ");
                clase1[contador] = scanner.nextInt();
                contador++;
                posicion++;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("A continuación debes entrar los valores de la"
                + "segunda clase.");
        contador = 0; posicion = 1;

        while (contador < clase2.length){
                System.out.print("Escribe el valor de la posición "+posicion+": ");
                clase2[contador] = scanner.nextInt();
                contador++;
                posicion++;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void resultado(int[]clase1, int[] clase2){
        System.out.println("Analisis de los datos coleccionados.\n");
        System.out.println("Colección 1:");
                for(int i=0; i < clase1.length; i++ ){
                    System.out.print(clase1[i]);
                }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in main method when calling resultado();
Is there something I do wrong? I just want to able to use the arrays created in intro() method in resultado() method.

Comment: Either return something and pass that or save them in instance fields and don't take args.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I have refactored the code for you, Please check my answer.

Comment: you didn't pass anything to resultado() when it's called.

Comment: Does your program say "An error", or does it give you more information about the error you got?  If it gives you more information, the info is very useful for figuring out what's causing the error.  Please don't keep it a secret from us.

Comment: @ajb, Its a basic compilation error, No Secret. Its straight forward

Comment: Seems like resultado() needs 2 int[] arguments that I'm not passing?

Comment: @SrikanthA Questions about basic compilation errors **must** include the error that the compiler outputs.  There is no excuse for saying "The compiler gave me an error", without providing details,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored your code for you, to split classes read to two methods.
From introGetClase1() and introGetClase2() methods, the int[] required for resultado() method is returned.

Arguments are passed to resultado() method

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Eac4P1_002 {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Método main
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Eac4P1_002 programa = new Eac4P1_002();
        programa.inicio();
    }
    //Método principal
    public void inicio() {
        presentacion();
        System.out.println("De que medida necesitas que sean las clases 1?");
        int medida = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] clase1 = introGetClase1(medida);
        int[] clase2 = introGetClase2(medida);
        resultado(clase1, clase2);
    }

    //Presentación
    public void presentacion(){
        System.out.println("Hola, bienvenid@ al ejercicio 2!\n"
                + "El programa os pedirá la edad de dos clases, "
                + "en enteros y comprueba si los valores de la segunda clase "
                + "son más grandes que los de la primera.");
    }
    //Inserción de datos
    public int[] introGetClase1(int medida){
        int clase1 [] = new int[medida];
        int contador = 0;
        int posicion = 1;

        System.out.println("Ahora deberás introducir el valor de cada "
                + "posición de la clase inicial.");
        while (contador < clase1.length){
            System.out.print("Escribe el valor de la posición "+posicion+": ");
            clase1[contador] = scanner.nextInt();
            contador++;
            posicion++;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return clase1;
    }

    //Inserción de datos
    public int[] introGetClase2(int medida){
        int clase2 [] = new int[medida];
        int contador = 0;
        int posicion = 1;

        while (contador < clase2.length){
            System.out.print("Escribe el valor de la posición (clases 2)"+posicion+": ");
            clase2[contador] = scanner.nextInt();
            contador++;
            posicion++;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return clase2;
    }

    public void resultado(int[]clase1, int[] clase2){
        System.out.println("Analisis de los datos coleccionados.\n");
        System.out.println("Colección 1:");
        for(int i=0; i < clase1.length; i++ ){
            System.out.print(clase1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did instead of just providing a section of code.

Comment: Explanation provided.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer ?, Nagative voter please comment !!

Comment: Seems like you almost nailed it, except now I keep having to add entries to class2.

Comment: If it looks fine, Please mark as answered - A tick to the answer.

Comment: In introGetClase1 it asks user for clase1 length that should be the same as introGetClase2. Any idea if I can apply same length to second array without asking again?

Comment: Move the reading of length a step above, in calling method and send the param. I have edited the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an array created in `intro()` as an input into `resultado()` consider adding a return value. `public void intro()` could be `public int[] intro()`.

```
public int[] intro(){
    System.out.println("De que medida necesitas que sean las clases?");
    int medida = scanner.nextInt();
    int clase1 [] = new int[medida];
    int contador = 0;
    int posicion = 1;

    System.out.println("Ahora deberás introducir el valor de cada "
                + "posición de la clase inicial.");
    while (contador < clase1.length){
            System.out.print("Escribe el valor de la posición "+posicion+": ");
            clase1[contador] = scanner.nextInt();
            contador++;
            posicion++;
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
return clase1;
}
```

Each time the method is called it will create a new array and return that array. So you could use it twice as input into `resultado()`.

```
resultado( intro() , intro() );
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are not passing anything when you call `resultado()`. that method requires an int array passed.

**For example:**

```
//Método principal
    public void inicio() {
        presentacion();
        intro();

        int[] ar1 = {1,2,3,4,};
        int[] ar2 = {2,3,4,5};
        resultado(ar1, ar2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your resultado(int[]clase1, int[] clase2) need two parameters.

```
 int[] class1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
 int[] class2 = {6,7,8,9,10}
 resultado(class1,class2);
```